# How to extract the member from single-member set in python?

Tags: python, set

I recently encountered a scenario in which if a set only contained a single element, I wanted to do something with that element.  To get the element, I settled on this approach:

```
element = list(myset)[0]
```

But this isn't very satisfying, as it creates an unnecessary list.  It could also be done with iteration, but iteration seems unnatural as well, since there is only a single element.  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but many of the answers to [Getting only element from a single-element list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33161448/364696) apply to this scenario as well (all the ones that avoid indexing and sequence-specific methods).

Comment: Classic example of where the question already contains the answer most people are looking for. :)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Tuple unpacking works, and verifies the assumption that the `set` contains *exactly* one element (raising `ValueError` if it has too many or too few elements).

```
(element,) = myset
# Or equivalently, without requiring trailing comma:
[element] = myset
```

(By the way, python-dev has explored but rejected the addition of `myset.get()` to return an arbitrary element from a set. [Discussion here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-October/093227.html), Guido van Rossum answers [1](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-October/093367.html) and [2](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-October/093412.html).)

My personal favorite for getting an arbitrary element is (when you have an unknown number, but also works if you have just one):

```
element = next(iter(myset)) ¹
```

*1*: in Python 2.5 and before, you have to use `iter(myset).next()`

Comment: Very nice! I like that this fails if the number of elements isn't 1.

Comment: @Laurence: That's a fine observation. Catch errors early, right?

Comment: Or, if you want to pretend Python has a proper operator for the job (your coworkers will hate you): `element ,= myset`

Comment: Suggested improvement: emphasize that the first will fail for a non-singleton set.

Comment: @rdb pep8 will hate you too

Comment: I'm not such a fan of that comma to tell python it's a tuple. How about ```[element] = myset```

Comment: The `next(iter(myset))` expression has the advantage of being usable without a special assignment, so you can pass it as an argument to a function, for example.

Answer (score 32):

Between making a tuple and making an iterator, it's almost a wash, but iteration wins by a nose...:

```
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=set([1])' 'a=tuple(x)[0]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.465 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=set([1])' 'a=tuple(x)[0]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.465 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=set([1])' 'a=next(iter(x))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.456 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=set([1])' 'a=next(iter(x))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.456 usec per loop
```

Not sure why all the answers are using the older syntax `iter(x).next()` rather than the new one `next(iter(x))`, which seems preferable to me (and also works in Python 3.1).

However, unpacking wins hands-down over both:

```
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=set([1])' 'a,=x'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.174 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=set([1])' 'a,=x'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.174 usec per loop
```

This of course is for single-item sets (where the latter form, as others mentioned, has the advantage of failing fast if the set you "knew" had just one item actually had several).  For sets with arbitrary N > 1 items, the tuple slows down, the iter doesn't:

```
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=set(range(99))' 'a=next(iter(x))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.417 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x=set(range(99))' 'a=tuple(x)[0]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.12 usec per loop
```

So, unpacking for the singleton case, and `next(iter(x))` for the general case, seem best.

Comment: Why Python2.x syntax? I only do real programming there, and `python` is Python 2.5 on my system, and hence what comes up when I press my keybinding to open a python console.

Comment: 2.6 is perfectly usable for "real programming" and richer than 2.5; the only reason to stick with 2.5 is if your external environment constrains you (App Engine, Civilization 4, etc). next(x) and x.next() both work in 2.6, but next(x) is better (lets you specify a default value rather than catching StopIteration exceptions, requires one fewer character;-).

Comment: @Alex: No need to convince me, I would much rather use python 2.6. I use debian, debian has not yet finished transitioning to Python 2.6! (Pyhthon 2.6 itself is available but none of the distributions 3rd part libraries.)

Comment: but since you mention that `next(..)` is available in Python 2.6, I now understand your point much better! That's good news.

Comment: @kaizer.se, yep -- similarly App Engine, as I mentioned, is also 2.5-only, as is Civilization IV (other scriptable games & apps can be even further behind), Mac OSX 10.5 (if you want to distribute apps that use the system Python rather than bundling their own) though 10.6 finally does use Python 2.6, and so forth -- there can be plenty of such environmental constraints forcing the use of 2.5 (or even earlier versions); but yep, 2.6 is appetizing when usable (the next built-in function is just one tidbit, but a juicy one;-).

Answer (score 26):

I reckon [kaizer.se's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619514/how-to-extract-the-member-from-single-member-set-in-python/1619539#1619539) is great. But if your set *might* contain more than one element, and you want a not-so-arbitrary element, you might want to use [`min`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) or [`max`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max). E.g.:

```
element = min(myset)
```

or:

```
element = max(myset)
```

(Don't use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted), because that has unnecessary overhead for this usage.)

Answer (score 18):

I suggest:

```
element = myset.pop()
```

Comment: This could work for some cases, but it mutates the set.

Comment: @recursive how about `element = myset.copy().pop()`

Comment: @recursive but does the mutation matter if it is a single-item set though?

Comment: @Astrid: For some use cases, yes.  For others, no.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `element = tuple(myset)[0]` which is a bit more efficient, or, you can do something like

```
element = iter(myset).next()
```

I guess constructing an iterator is more efficient than constructing a tuple/list.

Comment: Why do you guess constructing an iterator is more efficient?

Comment: @CraigMcQueen: Not sure why they "guessed" that, but, if the `set` is *not* guaranteed to be one-element long, constructing an iterator is `O(1)`, while constructing a `tuple`/`list` is `O(n)`. In local testing on 3.11.4, `next(iter(myset))` is faster than `tuple(myset)[0]` even when `myset` *is* a single element (~45 ns for `next`+`iter`, ~60 ns for `tuple(...)[0]`), with `elem, = myset` being the fastest (~35 ns), assuming you want to verify it's actually a single element `set`, and are okay with using a statement rather than an expression.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) which will work on a singleton set or a mulit-element set

`element, *_ = myset`

Though some bristle at the use of a throwaway variable.

Comment: The main flaw with this is that, despite being "throwaway" logically, Python still does the work to construct a `list` to hold the rest of it, and that `list` continues to exist until `_` is rebound/released (possibly longer if a cyclic reference was formed in some way, in which case it takes an arbitrary amount of time to get cleaned up, if ever). It's not a bad solution if you want to allow multi-element `set`s, and the `set` size is bounded at a low level, but if the `set` size is any meaningful size, `next(iter(myset))`'s higher fixed overhead, with `O(1)` perf, will beat the `O(n)` here.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `reduce` with `lambda x: x`.

```py
from functools import reduce

> reduce(lambda x: x, {3})
3

> reduce(lambda x: x, {1, 2, 3})
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

> reduce(lambda x: x, {})
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Benefits:

- Fails for multiple and zero values
- Doesn't change the original set
- Doesn't require data transformations (e.g., to list or iterable)
- Doesn't need a new variable and can be passed as an argument
- Arguably less awkward and PEP-compliant

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [more-itertools](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools) package. All functions below will return one item from the set, with different behaviors if the set does not contain exactly one item:

- [more_itertools.one](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.one) raises an exception if iterable is empty or has more than one item:

  ```py
  element = more_itertools.one(myset)
  ```

  This works like `(element,) = myset`, but might not be as fast:

  ```bash
  $ python3.11 -m timeit -s 'myset = {42}' '(element,) = myset'
  5000000 loops, best of 5: 57.9 nsec per loop
  $ python3.11 -m timeit -s 'from more_itertools import one
  myset = {42}' 'element = one(myset)'
  500000 loops, best of 5: 611 nsec per loop
  ```
- [more_itertools.only](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.only) returns a default if iterable is empty or raises an exception if iterable has more than one item:

  ```py
  element = more_itertools.only(myset)
  ```
- [more_itertools.first](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.first) raises an exception if iterable is empty, or a default when one is provided:

  ```py
  element = more_itertools.first(myset)
  ```

  This works as `element = next(iter(myset))`, but is arguably more idiomatic.
- [more_itertools.first_true](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.first_true) returns the first "truthy" value in the iterable or a default if iterable is empty:

  ```py
  element = more_itertools.first_true(myset)
  ```

You can also use the [first](https://github.com/hynek/first/) package:

```py
from first import first

element = first(myset)
```

This works like [more_itertools.first_true](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.first_true), mentioned above.