# Getting only element from a single-element list in Python?

Tags: python, list, iterable-unpacking

When a Python list is known to always contain a single item, is there a way to access it other than:

```
mylist[0]
```

You may ask, 'Why would you want to?'. Curiosity alone. There seems to be an alternative way to do *everything* in Python.

Comment: There may be alternatives, but there's usually only one *obvious* way to do it - and, in this case, you seem to have already found it.

Comment: if it *always* contains a single item, then maybe a `list` is not the best data type?

Comment: @ekhumoro: I'm actually partial to the sequence unpacking method, because it verifies the assumption that the sequence only has one element. `mylist[0]` succeeds when you have at least one element, but doesn't complain if you actually had 30 elements. `singleitem, = mylist` verifies that you've got exactly one element, no more, no less.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. The question is explicitly about accessing the only element in a list which is already *known* to contain a single item.

Comment: @ekhumoro: No disagreement. I just prefer to program defensively, so violations of requirements don't pass silently (sure it fails, but it fails loudly, which is much easier to identify and fix than subtle misbehaviors). If I had a nickel for every time some "known" behavior in production code turned out to be dead wrong... Well, I probably wouldn't be _rich_, but I'd be able to take the family out to a _really_ nice dinner.

Comment: @DavidZemens Surprisingly there could be reasonable use cases where you know that a list should always contain a single element. What comes to my mind: **a)** API which you cannot change, **b)** API planned to serve multiple items in the future, **c)** branch of the code where the list should always contain a single item

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong: A common case for this would be a generalized SQL query interface, where the number of items returned depends on the query itself. If you `SELECT a, b FROM foo;`, you'll get `n` two-tuples, if you `SELECT a FROM foo;` you get `n` one-tuples (it's generally not considered reasonable to dynamically vary the return type based on the arguments alone), while `SELECT a, b FROM foo LIMIT 1;` gets one two-tuple. Both of the latter two cases could reasonably involve unpacking a single-element sequence, with the last case being dependent on `foo` being non-empty.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

### Raises exception if not *exactly* one item:

##### Sequence unpacking:

```py
singleitem, = mylist
# Identical in behavior (byte code produced is the same),
# but arguably more readable since a lone trailing comma could be missed:
[singleitem] = mylist
```

##### Rampant insanity, unpack the input to the identity `lambda` function:

```
# The only even semi-reasonable way to retrieve a single item and raise an exception on
# failure for too many, not just too few, elements as an expression, rather than a
# statement, without resorting to defining/importing functions elsewhere to do the work
singleitem = (lambda x: x)(*mylist)
```

### All others silently ignore spec violation, producing first or last item:

##### Explicit use of iterator protocol:

```py
singleitem = next(iter(mylist))
```

##### Destructive pop:

```py
singleitem = mylist.pop()
```

##### Negative index:

```py
singleitem = mylist[-1]
```

##### Set via single iteration `for` (because the loop variable remains available with its last value when a loop terminates):

```
for singleitem in mylist: break
```

There are many others (combining or varying bits of the above, or otherwise relying on implicit iteration), but you get the idea.

Comment: The first one is unique in that it also raises if the list contains more than one element.

Comment: The first can also be written as `[singleitem] = mylist`.

Comment: @NeilG: Sadly, it's not wholly unique; the "rampant insanity" version in the comments does that too (as does the unpack via list syntax, though that's actually identical to the first example behavior-wise). I feel a bit dirty now.

Comment: @CarstenS: Usually, I frown on using `[]` for sequence unpacking (`for [i, x] in enumerate(iterable):` drives me batty), but yes, in the case of unpacking a single value, the trailing comma can easily be missed, and using brackets is justifiable for readability reasons. I've added it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I agree that it is not very pythonic, so I do not use it much any more, either. Only the old Haskeller in me wants to use it.

Comment: You can also use `ast` and prevent having a list with one element in the first place. #yolo

Comment: @Bharel: Huh? I don't see how the `ast` module is related here, and can't think what else you're referring to... It's not always possible to avoid a `list` if the API is limited.

Comment: In every node you encounter a list creation, you can prevent creating it in the first place. (hoping you won't wreck havoc). That way there will never be any single-element list.  Who needs them anyway.

Comment: You may also override builtins.list.__new__ and hope for good.

Comment: @Bharel: Okay, so as long as we're agreed that's batshit insane, we're good. :-)

Comment: `(singleitem,) = mylist` works too, of course. Somehow I can parse that one better.

Comment: @Nathan: Sure. The lone trailing comma is still relatively easy to miss though; if the code was written by an inexperienced programmer, and I was maintaining it, I'd be half inclined to read it as another manifestation of unnecessary parentheses disease (the same disease that leads to `return(retval)`, `if (x in y):`, etc.). The problem isn't parsing once you notice it, it's noticing it in the first place, and the square brackets (without a comma) are visible, and have no subtle details to miss.

Comment: I'll add `singleitem, *_ = mylist` (it's derived from `head, *tail = mylist`).

Comment: @DavidWaterworth: That silences the exception you'd get for passing a sequence with >1 item by silently collecting all the other items into `_` (making an empty `list` there if it's in fact single element); it's otherwise identical to `singleitem, = mylist`.

Comment: True, the safest/most explicit method may be to use something like https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.one - numpy has item() which I use frequently.

Comment: Very useful answer! Could you please just confirm (in the answer) that there is no solution in a form of an expression (not assignment) raising an exception if the sequence does not contain only just single item? ... not counting the tools not in the standard library like `more_itertools.one()`.

Comment: @pabouk: There technically is (someone just deleted the comment out of this comment chain apparently), it's just an insane solution I came up with (when I reference the "rampant insanity" version, that's the one), which is why I didn't put it in the answer. You'd just do: `(lambda x: x)(*mylist)`; `lambda`s are function definitions as expressions, so you can define one and then pass your unpacked iterable to one in a single line, and it either dies with an exception (if the unpacking doesn't match the argument count precisely) or calls the function successfully and returns the argument.

Comment: Black formats to `(x,) = xs`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: Eh. Black is *very* opinionated. `x, = xs` is probably a bad idea (in that it's easy to miss the comma), but `(x,) = xs` is ugly (still needs that comma, and it feels incomplete when nothing follows it). If Black just prefers `(x,) = xs` to `x, = xs`, that's fine, but if it prefers `(x,) = xs` over `[x] = xs`, I think it's going too far; the latter is prettier, functionally identical, and just an unambigious.

Comment: Unfortunately, black can't convert to `[x] = xs` since that is not an equivalent AST transformation and changes program behavior since it constructs a new list.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: The AST isn't the same, but it doesn't change program behavior at all; the two versions are *identical* per [the language spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements); "Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, is recursively defined as follows." Aside from that fact that `[]` eliminates the need for a trailing comma when unpacking to a single target due to *looking* like a `list` syntactically, they're both defined to be equivalent (no `tuple` or `list` is created).

Comment: Once the AST is compiled, they end up completely identical (a `LOAD_*` to load the original iterable to the stack, an `UNPACK_SEQUENCE 1` to assert it has one element and replace the item on the stack with that single element, and a `STORE_*` to put it in `x`). Granted, compiled opcodes aren't the spec, but since the end result supports the rules from the spec, it really is guaranteed to not change program behavior.

Answer (score 24):

I will add that the [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools)
library has a tool that returns one item from an iterable.

```
from more_itertools import one


iterable = ["foo"]
one(iterable)
# "foo"
```

In addition, [`more_itertools.one`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) raises an error if the iterable is empty or has more than one item.

```
iterable = []
one(iterable)
# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)

iterable = ["foo", "bar"]
one(iterable)
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

`more_itertools` is a third-party package `> pip install more-itertools`

Comment: Back when you wrote this answer, [`more_itertools.one` was exactly equivalent to my primary solution, aside from variable names](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/3.2.0/more_itertools/more.py#L420) (a two-liner, `element, = iterable`, then `return element`). It's since gotten *much* more complex (allowing custom exceptions for too short or too long, and therefore unable to benefit from unpacking performing the work efficiently, with Python raising exceptions for you). It's kind of a shame; it's rare the distinction matters, yet the code got much slower to accommodate it.

Comment: In particular, the new code is slower by the greatest margin for the success case (which is presumably the common case); in 3.11.1, the original implementation takes around 41 ns on a one-tuple on my machine, while the new one takes 348 ns. It's slower in the failure cases too (particularly when the iterable is too long), but those hardly matter (and the relative loss is much smaller, taking only 25-100% longer, not ~9x).

Answer (score 0):

(This is an adjusted repost of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619514/how-to-extract-the-member-from-single-member-set-in-python/71923494#71923494) to a similar question related to sets.)

One way is to use `reduce` with `lambda x: x`.

```py
from functools import reduce

> reduce(lambda x: x, [3]})
3

> reduce(lambda x: x, [1, 2, 3])
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

> reduce(lambda x: x, [])
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Benefits:

- Fails for multiple and zero values
- Doesn't change the original list
- Doesn't need a new variable and can be passed as an argument

Cons: "API misuse" (see comments).

Comment: This is stacking a lot of random garbage to get a result through, essentially, API misuse. It isn't gaining *any* benefit unique to the `lambda`, you could literally pass *any* function accepting *any* number of arguments aside from two (e.g. `ord`, `lambda: None`, etc.), and get the same result. It "works" because the function is never even called when there is only one thing in the input, and if it's called, it dies immediately. You may as well simplify it by just letting function call syntax do the job, as in my rampant insanity version (`(lambda x: x)(*mylist)`), with the same benefits.

Comment: To be clear, I enjoy stupid new ways to do simple things. I just don't support a claim that importing a function, and intentionally misusing it to get a benefit by side-effect from the misuse, is "Arguably less awkward and PEP-compliant" than literally any other solution out there. Also, just to be clear, this solution *does* involve transforming to an iterable; you don't see a call to `iter` because the language did it implicitly for you (the same way it does for unpacking, use of `for` loops, etc.).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the feedback. I adjusted the post base on them.