# finding crital value in python, problem with finite set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written program for finding critical value in Python.

My code:

```py
from sympy import *
def find_critical_points(f, x):
    fd = diff(f)
    dRoots = solveset(fd, x)
    a = Rational(float(dRoots))
    return a
```

And I wrote test for that:

```py
x = Symbol('x')
lst = find_critical_points(x**4+x**3, x)
assert lst == [-3/4,0]
lst = find_critical_points(x,x)
assert lst == []
```

Python return me error:

> float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'FiniteSet'

Please help with this error.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include `solveset`? It looks like whatever is being returned from their is causing errors in `a = Rational(float(dRoots))`

Comment: The problem is that float takes a string or a number, and parses it or converts it to float. You need to find a different way of transferring `FiniteSet` to a `Rational`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Others have given you good ideas, but we really want to *know* when we've solved your problem.

Comment: @Prune Hi did supply a minimal, reproducible example, including the error he was getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) takes a string or a number, and parses it or converts it to float.

With a [little research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439490/6673178), we can find that `FiniteSet` can be transferred directly to a Python list. So your code can go like this:

```py
from sympy import *


def find_critical_points(f, x):
    fd = diff(f)
    dRoots = solveset(fd, x)
    # a = Rational(float(dRoots))
    return list(dRoots)


x = Symbol('x')
lst = find_critical_points(x**4+x**3, x)
assert lst == [-3/4,0]
lst = find_critical_points(x,x)
assert lst == []
```