# Converting FiniteSet object to a python list

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, sympy

I'm looking for a way to easily manipulate the results given by the `solveset` method in the SymPy package. In particular, I have a function `omega(x,n,p,gamma)` and I want to compute its roots while keeping `gamma` as a symbolic variable:

```
def omega(x,n,p,gamma):
    #do stuff
    
gamma, x=var('gamma x')
roots=solveset(omega_complete(x,30,1,gamma), x)
```

`omega` returns a non-linear combination of `x` and `gamma`, so other methods in the same library such as `linsolve` or `solve` do not work. Currently I am stuck with an output of type `FiniteSet` after calling `solveset`: the result is printed in LaTeX and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYuVA.gif).

The naive conversion `list(roots)` gives the error `TypeError: did not evaluate to a bool: None`. The alternative way that I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418205/get-a-value-from-solution-set-returned-as-finiteset-by-sympy) using `roots.args[0], roots.args[1]` is also not what I'm looking for. Can anyone help?

---

The full code (note that are actually two functions, `omega_complete` and `omega_cycle`, that are similarly defined):

```
import numpy as np
import cmath as cm
from sympy import *

def target(n,p):
    w=[]
    for j in range(n):
        if j==p:
            w.append(1)
        else: w.append(0)
    return np.array(w)

###---complete---####

def change_basis_complete(N):
    
    matrix=np.zeros((N,N),dtype=complex)
    for n in range(0,N):
        for m in range(0,N):
            matrix[n,m]=(1/cm.sqrt(N))*cm.exp(2*np.pi*1j*(n+1)*(m+1)/N)
    return matrix  

def new_target_complete(N,p):
    return np.dot(change_basis_complete(N),target(N,p))

def omega_complete(x,N,p,gamma):
    
    w=new_target_complete(N,p)
    
    old_spectrum=np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(N-1):
        old_spectrum[i]=N
    old_spectrum[N-1]=0
    
    sigma=0
    for i in range(N):
        sigma+=(abs(w[i])**2)/(gamma*old_spectrum[i]-x)
    return 1-sigma

###---cycle---####

def change_basis_cycle(N):
    
    matrix=np.zeros((N,N),dtype=complex)
    for n in range(0,N):
        for m in range(0,N):
            matrix[n,m]=(1/cm.sqrt(N))*cm.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*(n+1)*(m+1)/N)
    return matrix  

def new_target_cycle(N,p):
    return np.dot(change_basis_cycle(N),target(N,p))

def omega_cycle(x,N,p,gamma):
    
    w=new_target_cycle(N,p)
    
    old_spectrum=np.zeros(N)
    for n in range(N):
        old_spectrum[n]=2-2*cm.cos((2*cm.pi*n)/N)
   
    sigma=0
    for i in range(N):
        sigma+=(abs(w[i])**2)/(gamma*old_spectrum[i]-x)
    return 1-sigma
```

Comment: What about `list(roots.args)`?

Comment: Are you sure it's a FiniteSet? If it is then I think `list(roots)` should work. It's hard to comment given that your code is incomplete but perhaps you could show the output from `srepr(roots)`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thank you, `list(roots.args)` seems to be working. Yes, it is `FiniteSet`, but strangely enough `list()` does not work! There is still one last issue, for which I should probably ask a separate question. `solveset` does not specify the multiplicity of the roots, and besides the data it returns are organized in a pretty strange way: as you can see in the image above the converted output is a nested list with two elements each. Weird, huh?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it!

Comment: @OscarBenjamin One last thing: do you happen to know how to deal if the result is of type `ConditionSet`? The same approach gives me an error (`ConditionSet` object is not iterable).

Comment: Can you show the actual examples in the question? You don't need to show all the code calling `solveset` just `srepr(roots)` to show the output from `solveset`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I've made a pastebin with the result of calling `srepr(roots)` with `roots=solveset(omega_cycle(x,4,1,gamma), x)`: the link is https://pastebin.com/5bcB14xD.

Comment: Actually the best thing would be to show what `omega_cycle(x,4,1,gamma)` is. I'm guessing it's a polynomial and you would be better off using `roots` rather than `solveset`

Comment: @OscarBenjamin At this point it's probably best if I simply add the full code, it's actually not that long or complicated. You can find it above!

Answer (score 0):

SymPy [issues](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) would love to know the equation you are trying to solve so this can be reproduced: there is no reason that `list(finite_set_object)` should not give you a list of the args. But if `list(finite_set_object.args)` works...hmm.

Regarding the ConditionSet or any of the other objects that `solveset` returns, you have to read what they mean to understand what you can do with them. Often, ConditionSet is returned like `ConditionSet(Eq(eq, 0), domain)` to say "the solution of eq = 0 was not found" and so there is no way to convert that to a list of solutions.

Comment: I can add the code to the github page, no problem. As for the ConditionSet object, what does it mean exactly that no solution is found? I know for sure that my equation has a certain number of real solutions. Could it be due to the complexity of the calculation?

Comment: An equation can have numerical solutions that cannot be represented in closed form. I can't tell unless you show the equation.

Comment: The output is now linked to in a comment on the OP. It is a Complement set rather than a FiniteSet. The finite set can be obtained with `.args[0]`.

Comment: The link in the OP shows a single opening and closing brace around two elements i.e., a FiniteSet. Perhaps the link changed? It would be good to have the right link there.

Comment: First of all, thank you both for your interest. I have added the full code in the original post, to remove all possible doubts. It's not very long or complicated to read, I hope.

Comment: OK, I can see it is a Complement but in the pic that is shown in the link the " \ {0, 30.0⋅γ}" part is missing: that means "...but x cannot be 0 or 30.0⋅γ."