# Unpack return value from length-1 tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, tuples

Let's say I have a dummy function which returns exactly what give as a parameter:

```
def dummy_single(arg1):
    """Repeat the same argument."""
    return arg1
```

I can use this function on the following way:

```
same_obj1 = dummy_single(obj1)
```

Now, if I want to allow this function to take several arguments, and return the same, I can pack and unpack the arguments:

```
def dummy_multiple(*args):
    """Repeat all given arguments."""
    return args
```

*Please note that this function happens to be the identity, but this is not the core of the problem. You can imagine any function returning a variable-length tuple.*

It works pretty well when called with multiple arguments:

```
same_obj1, same_obj2 = dummy_multiple(obj1, obj2)
```

However, this won't work as expected:

```
same_tuple = dummy_multiple(obj1)
```

`same_obj1` contains a (packed) tuple, as opposed to the object in the two previous example. I thought about fixing this behavior on the following way, but it does not look clean as the returned type is different depending on the arguments.

```
def dummy_multiple_fixed(*args):
    """Repeat all given arguments."""
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    return args
```

This is not a critical issue and is easily fixed. But I cannot find a clean and elegant way to fix this issue.

Comment: Relevant/related question: [Getting only element from a single-element list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33161448/364696) (the same approaches apply to unpacking a single-element `tuple`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not make a special case out of the length-1 tuple. A function should have one well-defined return type.

Although,  know that you can unpack a length-1 tuple:

```
def dummy_multiple(*args):
    """Repeat all given arguments."""
    return args

same_obj1, = dummy_multiple(1)
#        ^ notice the comma here

print(same_obj1) # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the accepted answer - whether or not a function should have a single return type depends on the use case and the semantics of the specific function. Particularly so because failing to anticipate a tuple will not throw an error immediately, but rather will cause an issue later in the code.

I have been looking into the same issue as the original question, and was thinking  that having to call a function like

```
single_arg, = process(single_arg)
```

is not intuitive at all.
I find the following approach from [Huggingface Accelerate library](https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate/blob/6719cb6db31f57ea5d2fdb179b0487f51718f353/src/accelerate/accelerator.py#L1249C16-L1249C56) a lot more user-friendly:

```
return result if len(result) > 1 else result[0]
```

That way the calls to the function are more uniform:

```
single_arg = process(single_arg)
multi_args1, multi_args2 = process(multi_args1, multi_args2)
```

Comment: *”A function should have one well-defined return type.”* if it’s not so, then it’s not a function, it is a mess. **A function** *f* **from a set** *X* **to a set** *Y* **is an assignment of an element of** *Y* **to each element of** *X*. **The set** *X* **is called the domain of the function and the set** *Y* **is called the codomain of the function**. If a function does not meet this definition, it is not a function.

Comment: The answer is based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon that definition is from maths and has nothing to do with programming languages or code. People came up with weakly-typed programming languages for that exact reason of not wanting to sacrifice common sense&convenience for the sake of following arbitrary syntax constraints.