# Cannot get an index of a list item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these two lists:

`list1= [1, 3, 8, 14, 20]`

`list2= [1, 2, 7, 8, 14, 20]`

I obtained the common items between these two lists as follow:
`commonItems=list(set(list1).intersection(list2))`

now randomly picked one of the common items as :

`pick=random.sample(commonItems,1)`

Now, when I try to identify the picked item index in one of the above lists as :
`PickedItemIndex=list1.index(pick)`

I got this error:
ValueError: [8] is not in list

even if, as you can see, item 8 really exists in list1

what is the problem?
I am a new pythonic. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the type of variable `pick` is a `list`.

You need to pass an `int` to the `index` command:

```
In [314]: list1.index(pick[0])
Out[314]: 4
```

Comment: Note: An alternative approach is to use the knowledge that [there is exactly one element picked to unpack it at time of selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161467/364696), so it's the expected scalar value, e.g. `[pick] = random.sample(commonItems, 1)` will unpack the resulting `list` immediately, so you can use `pick` directly without indexing thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because the variable 'pick' is a list.
The code below will run without an error:

```
pick=random.sample(commonItems,1)
PickedItemIndex=list1.index(pick[0])
```

pick[0] is the first item of the list 'pick' (that contains only 1 element)