# How to remove double [] from a list?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list like this:

```
  my_lst = [[1,2,3,4]]
```

I was wondering how can I remove [] from the list to get the following list:

```
 my_lst = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: @Sociopath: It might be inside a `dict`, and it's technically a legal type annotation in modern Python, but yes, on its own, it's unlikely to be what anyone actually wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_lst = my_lst[0]
```

You have a list with one element, which is itself a list.  You want the variable to just be that first element, the list 1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 4):

The double `[[]]` is because you have a `list` containing a `list`. To get out the inner `list`, just index it:

```
my_lst = my_lst[0]
```

or unpack it:

```
[my_lst] = my_lst
```

Unpacking has the mild advantage that it will give you an error if the outer `list` doesn't not contain exactly one value (while `my_lst[0]` will silently discard any extra values).

[There are many other options.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161467/364696)

Answer (score 2):

you have a list of lists.

```
my_lst = my_lst[0] #get the first list of the list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` to achieve that without writing your explicit loop if the length of the outer list could be more than one.

```
In [47]: import itertools                                                       


In [49]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]))                       
Out[49]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce 1 dimension using `sum`.

```
my_lst=sum(my_lst,[])
# [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: This is a really terrible general approach. It happens to be fine (if somewhat weird) for the single inner `list` case, but it's a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm) when it comes to generalized flattening of an iterable of `list`s, with quadratic runtime (where `list`ifying the iterator produced by `itertools.chain`/`itertools.chain.from_iterable` is the correct solution for that case, having linear runtime).