# functools reduce() gives TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reduce, functools

I am having problem with functools.reduce().
It returns int object is not subscriptable

```
total_population = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a[0] + b[0], mid_points)
```

variable 'mid_points' list of tuples: sample is given in picture below

But when I tried above line of code on:

```
li = [(1,"a"), (2,"b")]
```

it gives correct output i.e 3

Please help! what am I do?

[image: sample of mid_points]

Comment: `a[0] + b[0]` returns an int, which will be fed as `a` into the next iteration…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `reduce` needs to be a valid *input* to the reduction function; you reduction function expects a sequence with at least one element, but you're returning an `int`. Just change the code to:

```
[total_population] = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0],), mid_points)
```

to add a layer of `tuple` wrapping so indexing continues to work, and the [brackets at the end unpack the resulting single element `tuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161467/364696). This will break if `mid_points` is a single element, so if that's possible:

```
total_population, *_ = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0],), mid_points)
```

is slightly safer, as it just captures any extra elements in the result into an ignored `list`.

An alternative (thanks for reminding me @deceze) is to give `reduce` a starting value, so `a` is always an `int`, both on the first call and all subsequent calls:

```
total_population = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b[0], mid_points, 0)
```

The final argument to `reduce` is the first `a` and all subsequent `a`s are results of previous calls. Of course, this can also be simplified in a third way to avoid `reduce` entirely:

```
from operator import itemgetter

total_population = sum(map(itemgetter(0), mid_points))

# Or without an import, but ever-so-slightly slower:
total_population = sum(pt[0] for pt in mid_points)
```

since really you just need to do two things; extract the first element of each input, and sum them.

Comment: I'd rather go with adding a starting parameter for `reduce` to ensure `a` is *always* an integer…

Comment: @deceze: Sure. I'll add that.

Comment: Thank you! Finally understood what was wrong with my code.