# Getting an element of a list without if or for blocks in python

Tags: python

Few days ago, in my exam I had this question:
4. Rewrite the following code without if statement. The code should be single line. (without using any other loops)

```
If not flora and fauna:
      return True
else:
      return False
```

I could not answer for this question but still it seems very interesting/strange for me since I'm not pro in python. I have tried a lot of ways like `extend()` function but still don't know how to do this.

Any ideas or hints?

EDIT: I framed the question wrongly. Sorry for this. Since I do not have much experience I thought this problem can be solved only by making lists.

Comment: That's not valid python... (Capital if)

Comment: Little unclear what this has to do with `for` loops, or `extend` or getting an element of a `list`. I don't see any `list`s here, nor any reason to use them or otherwise loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you return `True` when the `if` is true, and `False` when it's false, the straightforward solution is to just return what the `if` is evaluating directly:

```
return not flora and fauna
```

Note that this might not return `True` or `False`, but rather a truthy or falsy value (e.g. for a falsy `flora`, the expression evaluates to whatever `fauna` is; if `flora, fauna = 0, "Spam"`, the expression evaluates to `"Spam"`, which is truthy, but not `True`), and `fauna` is `"Spam"`. If you need a true `True`/`False`, just convert to `bool`:

```
return bool(not flora and fauna)
```

or use a conditional expression to achieve the same effect:

```
return True if not flora and fauna else False
```

or (we're getting into "playing around for fun territory now):

```
return not not (not flora and fauna)
```

or (distribute one `not`):

```
return not (flora or not fauna)
```

or (faster than `bool`, slower than `not not`, probably not worth the import though):

```
from operator import truth

return truth(not flora and fauna)
```

99+% of the time though, you don't need true `True`/`False`, so `return not flora and fauna` is really the way to go.

Comment: Lol. I didn't know there's a truth operator

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yup. And it's faster than `bool`, because `bool` is a constructor (that can't avoid some overhead and flexibility involved in constructors that `bool` doesn't benefit from since it always returns an existing object), while `operator.truth` is a simple function. The only real advantage to `bool` is you can call it without arguments (where `truth` requires exactly one positional argument). `bool` is faster than it used to be (they finally banned keyword arguments for it in 3.7, that lets it use much simpler argument parsing), but still slower than `truth`.

Comment: Just for comparison, on my Python x64 3.8.5 Alpine Linux install (running under WSLv2), in `ipython3`, `%%timeit x = False; from operator import truth as t` with a test body of `t(x)` runs in about 32 ns per loop; `%%timeit x = False; b = bool` with a test body of `b(x)` is about 69 ns per loop. Of course, using `not not x` gets it down to 20.5 ns, and using plain `x` is 11 ns, so the real answer is to not worry about `True`/`False` and just return the truthy/falsy thing.

Comment: If both are bools, you could also do `return flora < fauna`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sure, but that's making pretty strict assumptions with little way to ensure that they're valid. You're not supposed to care about whether a given value is actually a `bool` (idiomatic code that actually needs `True`/`False` typed out in it is fairly uncommon), but that solution requires it, and silently misbehaves in many cases where the assumption is violated.

Comment: Well I wouldn't use it in those cases. And I wouldn't call it an assumption. When I write code, I *know* the possible types of my data. I probably wouldn't get much right if I didn't :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy: I've [said it before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161448/getting-only-element-from-a-single-element-list-in-python/33161467#comment54132042_33161448), and I'll say it again: "If I had a nickel for every time some 'known' behavior in production code turned out to be dead wrong... Well, I probably wouldn't be *rich*, but I'd be able to take the family out to a *really* nice dinner." I like my code to (as much as possible) either do the right thing silently all the time, or fail loudly when the assumptions are violated; I don't trust myself like you do. :-)