# Turn a list of single tuples into a list without tuples

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

I'm working with lists of single tuples that looks like this:

```
data = [[('jog',), ('Jim',), ('jell',), ('jig',)], [('jabs',), ('jilt',), ('job',), ('jet',)]]
```

Notice that the list contains two elements: two lists containing 4 tuples. Basically, I'm just trying to remove each tuple and make it look like this:

```
data = [['jog','Jim','jell','jig'], ['jabs','jilt','job','jet']]
```

I think this can probably be done with list comprehension, but I've tried for hours and can't come up with the magic formula. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do your inner lists always have exactly 4 tuples?

Comment: Also, why do you have such data? Maybe that can instead be *prevented* by fixing the code that produced this?

Answer (score 2):

The listcomp "magic formula" you're looking for is best done with a nested listcomp using unpacking in the innermost listcomp:

```
data = [[x for [x] in sublist] for sublist in data]
```

The `[x]` there triggers [the unpacking of the single element `tuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161467/364696) in the most efficient manner possible (while also verifying it is in fact *exactly* one element per `tuple`, no more, no less). Otherwise it's a largely no-op nested listcomp.

Comment: How is using `[x for [x] in sublist]` different than using `[x[0] for x in sublist]`?

Comment: @user107511: Two improvements: 1) It's faster (indexing takes ~20% longer; indexing is weirdly slow in CPython; that may improve with 3.11, which adds self-optimizing bytecode for integer indexing of `list`/`tuple` IIRC). 2) It verifies the OP's assumption that it's a `list` of `list` of one-`tuple`s (technically, any iterable of iterables of one-element iterables would work; close enough). If any of those nested `tuple`s are actually 2+ elements (or empty, but indexing would handle that), this will die with an exception, where indexing would just silently discard the elements above index 0.

Comment: @user107511 If the inner list has small fixed size as well, we can even [take this further](https://ideone.com/hTBqhw) (see the benchmark results at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
data = [[('jog',), ('Jim',), ('jell',), ('jig',)], [('jabs',), ('jilt',), ('job',), ('jet',)]]
data = [[tup[0] for tup in lst] for lst in data]
print(data)
# [['jog', 'Jim', 'jell', 'jig'], ['jabs', 'jilt', 'job', 'jet']]
```

Comment: Minor weakness here: It will silently discard data if it turns out an inner `tuple`s *isn't* a singleton. It's also slightly slower than unpacking (it's a minor loss if this isn't the hottest code path, only a 20% increased runtime).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten your tuples in a list, you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools

data = [[('jog',), ('Jim',), ('jell',), ('jig',)], [('jabs',), ('jilt',), ('job',), ('jet',)]]

result = [list(itertools.chain(*d)) for d in data]

# result = [['jog', 'Jim', 'jell', 'jig'], ['jabs', 'jilt', 'job', 'jet']]
```