# python from List[Tuple[str]] to List[str]

Tags: python, dictionary

I have something like this:

```
[('a',), ('b',), ('c',),('d',)]
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

This is what I tried:

```
p = [('a',), ('b',), ('c',),('d',)]
[el[0] for el in p]
```

is there a more "pythonic way " to do that? I would like to avoid using a for loop as my list consist of 165400 tuples

Comment: I don't think you can do it any faster than a for loop or list comprehension, this is fundamentally O(n)

Comment: In what sense do you think the list comprehension may not be "Pythonic"?

Comment: The list comprehension you have seems perfectly pythonic.

Comment: List comprehension is certainly faster than using `itertools.chain` to unpack a list of tuples

Comment: try to find a **flatten** operation that is implemented in C

Comment: You could do `list(map(lambda x : x[0], p))`, but I think the list comprehension is better and more readable (and also faster!).

Comment: Just curious: Can you change the data source so that it outputs a list of strings instead of single-element tuples?

Comment: You could use `flattened_list = sum(your_list, [])` but idk if it's any faster or more pythonic

Comment: @MattPitkin Using *map()* is functionally correct but significantly slower than the list comprehension

Comment: @DerSchinken Since you can't add tuples to a list, your suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: @DerSchinken: That's going to be substantially slower for large inputs, even if you fix it to use a `tuple` as the base; it's repeated concatenation, throwing away the old `tuple` each time to build new `tuple`s at *every* step. It's `O(n²)` where it could be `O(n)`.

Comment: Are the tuples guaranteed to be singletons?

Comment: @JohnColeman That form of unpacking is significantly slower than OP's 0-index approach (Python 3.12). Interestingly, ShadowRanger's elegant proposition of *[e for e, in _list]* is faster

Comment: @DarkKnight I still remember when my Teacher in university suggested me to avoid using for loop when it is possible to use  "built in " function cause they are built in C so they are really really faster. So this is what I mean

Comment: @NicWorkAccount: The built-ins can be a little faster, but in the last three releases of Python, they've made some massive improvements to the interpreter, such that the cost of Python-level code has gone down dramatically (especially in the move from 3.10 to 3.11). `map` with a built-in implemented in C can still beat an equivalent listcomp for a large enough input, but the difference is shrinking. I'll add some brief performance notes to my answer to make this clear.

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine certainly? I'm skeptical. Why do you say that?

Comment: @DerSchinken **no** That is a *well known antipattern* that is *definitely slower algorithmically*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: As it happens, the listcomp is *much* faster. See my answer. `itertools.chain` just isn't well-suited to the use case of flattening an iterable of one-`tuple`s (not sufficiently specialized). That's not the case all the time (`chain` should win for an iterable of non-trivially sized iterables, though I haven't tested it in the 3.11 timeframe though), but for this case, yeah, `chain` ends up pretty terrible. Not as terrible as the `sum(p, ())` anti-pattern, but not great either.

Comment: @NicWorkAccount Just to be clear, are the inner tuples guaranteed to be of length 1? If they're not, should the output have only the first elements from each tuple, or all elements from each tuple?

Answer (score 8):

To assert that the `tuple`s are in fact one element each, so you get an exception if the assumption is violated, rather than silently discarding data, you can use iterable unpacking in any of the following three forms to [extract the element from a known single-element iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161467/364696):

```
[el for el, in p]
[el for (el,) in p]
[el for [el] in p]
```

All three are 100% equivalent in behavior and performance, it's mostly about which form you feel is most readable.

As a bonus, unpacking is typically a little faster than indexing (only about 5-10% on Python 3.11, not enough to worry about if you *wanted* to ignore extra elements, but if your code's correctness *relies* on the assumption that there is exactly one element per `tuple`, this gets you that check automatically, with *negative* cost).

If the `tuple`s might be variable length and you *want* to keep the contents, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is the way to go:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(p))  # Or [*chain.from_iterable(p)] if you prefer
```

which will avoid discarding any data.

Lastly, if you're just looking to optimize taking the first element and you're really okay with your assumptions being violated, you *could* micro-optimize this a tiny bit for large inputs:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list(map(itemgetter(0), p))  # Or [*map(itemgetter(0), p)] if you prefer
```

but that's a small, and shrinking (as they make the interpreter faster) benefit over the listcomp, and probably not worth the trouble unless you're *sure* this is the hot loop and there is no way to change what you're doing to improve it algorithmically.

---

#### On Performance

Some performance notes to address your concern about "`for` loops" due to "my Teacher in university suggested me to avoid using for loop when it is possible to use "built in " function cause they are built in C so they are really really faster".

1. Plain `for` loops repeatedly appending to a `list` will be slower.

   ```
   lst = []
   for x, in p:
       lst.append(x)
   ```

   will lose out on performance due to the cost of repeatedly loading `lst` from the stack, looking up its `append` method, and calling it through generalized code paths. That said, as of 3.11, they put a bunch of cached and self-modifying/specializing bytecode in the interpreter, so it doesn't actually cost *that* much more anymore.
2. `map` with a built-in function implemented in C can win. But even before 3.11, the gains were small (if unpacked to a `list`, typically no more than 10% faster than an equivalent listcomp, and only slightly faster than that against the higher CPU overhead generator expression equivalent). As of 3.11, with the *massive* interpreter speed improvements, the differences have shrunk even more.

For a case example, here's the timings I get running IPython microbenchmarks on Python 3.11.6 on my local machine, making a 10K element `list` of one-`tuple`s, then converting it to a `list` of their contents with one of the three approaches given in the main body of my answer, or the explicit `for` loop I mentioned as being slower:

```
>>> import random
>>> from itertools import chain; from operator import itemgetter
>>> %%timeit p = [(random.randrange(1000),) for _ in range(10000)]
... [x for x, in p]
...
346 µs ± 2.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit p = [(random.randrange(1000),) for _ in range(10000)]
... [*map(itemgetter(0), p)]
...
344 µs ± 2.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit p = [(random.randrange(1000),) for _ in range(10000)]
... [*chain.from_iterable(p)]
...
491 µs ± 1.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit p = [(random.randrange(1000),) for _ in range(10000)]
... lst = []
... for x, in p:
...     lst.append(x)
...
388 µs ± 12.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

As you can see:

- `map` with `itemgetter(0)` (both of which are C-level built-ins, though `itemgetter` could stand to be optimized a titch better for special cases like being given a single integer index) does win, but only barely; a mere 2 µs difference per loop (and the standard deviation is higher than the difference; in further runs, `map` did tend to win more often than not, but it wasn't a sure thing), less than 1% of the total time.
- Using `chain.from_iterable` lost *badly*, despite being a built-in implemented entirely in C, presumably because `chain` assumes the sub-iterables can be anything and has no optimizations for `tuple`s, let alone one-`tuple`s (it constructs an iterator for each of them, pulls from it twice, with the second pull failing each time, and moves on to the next). Being a C built-in is no guarantee of speed if it can't specialize to the task at hand.
- While the plain `for` loop, without a listcomp involved, did lose, it only took about 12% longer than the listcomp, and 13% longer than `map`. I'd favor the listcomp over the plain `for` loop for brevity and clarity, reserving the `for` loop for more complicated work, but speed-wise? Not going to be your problem. Actually processing the data will almost certainly involve an order of magnitude or so more effort (you're getting this from a database, which, unless it's an SQLite DB in memory, involves disk or network access, either of which will be *much* slower than Python); unpacking it is going to be a pretty irrelevant to the overall performance of your code.

Comment: `[*chain(*p)]` if you are after brevity =) the `from_iterable` part is quite unnecessary if you consume all of them all the way and turn it into a list anyway.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  it is the result of an Sqlalchemy query where I select only one column . So yeah I am sure of tuple's length

Comment: @NicWorkAccount: Yeah, then definitely go with one of the unpacking solutions. The unpacking validates your assumption for free (if you change the query such that it now returns two columns, and forget to change the listcomp, it will raise a `ValueError`, rather than silently discarding the second column and leaving you wondering why it's missing later on like indexing would), and does it slightly more efficiently than indexing (the difference is pretty small by 3.11 which optimized indexing a bit, but even so, for large inputs the unpacking takes about 8% less time on my machine).

Comment: @user2390182: The `from_iterable` does save a shallow copy of the `list` (star unpacking to a function shallow copies it to a `tuple`, which `chain` then gets an iterator from, exactly the same way `from_iterable` does directly to the `list` without a shallow copy). Admittedly not likely to be a big performance hit, relative to whatever you *do* with the resulting `chain` object, but it's `O(n)` work you didn't have to do (for a 10K element `list`, `chain(*lst)` takes 44.2 *µ*s, `chain.from_iterable(lst)` takes 96.2 *n*s; unpacking increased setup time by over 450x).

Comment: Just to be clear, running out the `chain` is going to be an order of magnitude more expensive than creating it even in the slow way, so it's not the end of the world to use star unpacking, but just for comparison, running it out to make a new `list` still leaves a noticeable difference for the 10K `list` of one-`tuple`s: `[*chain(*lst)]` took 524 µs, while `[*chain.from_iterable(lst)]` took 481 µs (roughly as expected given the difference in setup costs; running them out should take the same time, since it's just a matter of whether it's using a `tuple` or `list` iterator, both are fast).

Comment: If anyone is wondering, the timings in the comments are from a different (faster) machine than the timings in the answer, so don't compare comments to answer. The relative differences within the answer and the comments are what matters.

Comment: Hmm, I get 160 us for the list comp and 440 us for chain, a much bigger difference (CPython 3.11.4). And 280 us for `reduce(iconcat, p, [])`. What do you get for that?

Comment: @KellyBundy: Odd. I'm running on Alpine (where libmusl might mess with things vs. libc) under WSL2 (which also might affect things), on a laptop (with power saving measures disabled though). The timings are probably more variable than on a desktop (even with power saving disabled, laptop processors can be weird), but they don't vary that much from test to test. `reduce(iconcat, p, [])` is 440 µs (across several runs, it varied between 434 and 447, but always slow relative to everything but `chain`). *shrugs* No idea why it differs. IPython 8.3.0 if that matters.