# Assignment of a sliceable object single element

Tags: python

It recently came to my eyes that in:

```
a = [1]
 

print(a, type(a))

[b] = a

print(b)

b = a[0]


a = [1,2]

b = a[0]

print(b)

try :
    
    [b] = a
    
except Exception as e:
    
    print(e)
```

The notation `[b] = a` could actually work.

Why does it work, is it relevant in more complex situations? Does it work against *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it"*?

Comment: [_"Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets..."_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) - so there are three ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a weird looking case of the general unpacking syntax, used in contexts like swapping two variables without a temporary:

```
a, b = b, a
```

or just unpacking directly in other contexts, e.g. iterating over keys and values of a `dict`:

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
```

The outer brackets are usually optional (`[a, b] = b, a` and `for [key, value] in mydict.items():` would work the same, but there's no reason to include the brackets), but when it's unpacking a single value, you need either the brackets or an isolated trailing comma, which can easily be missed:

```
b, = a
# Or with optional parens, also legal tuple syntax
(b,) = a

# This is *not* the same, it's exactly equivalent to plain b = a
# because without the comma, parens group, they don't delimit a tuple
(b) = a
```

It's different from simple indexing, because [it verifies that there is *exactly* one element, no more, no less, raising an exception if that assumption is violated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161467/364696); simple indexing only informs you if the sequence is too short, not too long.

Comment: Interesting(?) that `(b) = ...` is the same as `b = ...` **not** `[b] = ...` (or `(b,) = ...`, `b, = ...`) - it specifically must be brackets `[]` not parentheses `()` for that case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yep. It's borrowing the syntax from `tuple` and `list`s, and plain parentheses, without a comma, are for grouping, they don't make a `tuple` (outside of the empty `tuple` case). I added an example of that in the final code block just to preempt that confusion.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Also then `() = ...` or `[] = ...` is a "fun" way to check if an iterable is empty!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yep. That's rarely useful (because checking if it's empty is usually the step before drawing off the first non-empty value, which that attempt would consume in the process of checking), you'd usually just use truthiness testing (for collections) or `next(iterator)` (for iterators), but if you really only care to verify the *expectation* that is empty, you could do that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `(b) = ...` is the same a `b = ...` since parentheses are only used for grouping in python. A tuple is defined by the commas.

Comment: thanks for the 33161448/getting-only-element-from-a-single-element-list-in-python/33161467#33161467 link , didnt find it before I upvoted you there

Comment: the question arose because I used this expression in one of my answers. yes, I specifically meant to express that the list I'm unpacking is supposed to have one element, and the program should ***fail if not***.

Answer (score 1):

`[b] = a` isn't doing what you think.

This unpacks all items from `a` and assigns them to the variables between the brackets.

Since you have more that one value in `a` this fails.

Example that works:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]

[a, b, c] = x

print(a)
# 1

print(c)
# 3
```

Note that you could also use `a, b, c = x`

Partial unpacking:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

b, *_ = a

print(b)
# 1
```

Comment: didnt know about b, *_ = a too , thanks a lot