# Pythonic way to "merge" strings, handling all possible lengths

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics

I'm trying to solve a fairly common problem in bioinformatics without resorting to a bunch of if statements.

**The problem at hand:**

I'm given two overlapping strings and a length of the expected output, and I want to produce a merged string. Here all the ways the strings might overlap: (in the following examples a `-` denotes that there is nothing in that string at that position. the `consensus()` bit is explained after the examples.):

```
# size=13
xxxOVERLAP---
---OVERLAPyyy
# expected output: xxx + consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP) + yyy


# size=7
---OVERLAPxxx
yyyOVERLAP---
# expected output: consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP)


# size=7
OVERLAP
OVERLAP
# expected output: consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP)

# size=10
xxxOVERLAP
---OVERLAP
# expected output: xxx + consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP)

# size=10
OVERLAP---
OVERLAPyyy
# expected output: consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP) + yyy

# size > len(x) + len(y)
# no overlap, produce error:
xxx---
---yyy
# expected output: error
```

The resulting merged string needs to **start with the beginning of `x`** and **end with the end of `y`**. **The region that overlaps need to be passed to another function, `consensus()` that deals with merging the overlapped region.** Here all the ways the strings might overlap: (in the following examples a `-` denotes that there is nothing in that string at that position)

```
def merge(x, y, size):
    # do the mergeing
    return part of x that doesn't overlap + consensus(overlap) + part of y that doesn't overlap.
```

I can code up a mess of if statements to recognize each case and deal with it individually, but I've been struggling to find a more elegant solution. One approach I considered is padding the strings (the end of x and the beginning of y) so that all cases look like the second example, but this seems too inefficient to be palatable, since i'd be making new strings when i did that and I'm applying this function to millions of strings.

Comment: I don't follow the description. In your examples, you provide three inputs, but did not provide the output for each example.

Comment: editted to show expected output

Comment: You can start from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: in this case, I know the size of the string I want upfront, so the overlap is a deterministic function of the size of `x`, `y`, and the given `size`. Also, the `OVERLAP` region doesn't necessarily match 100%, which is why i need to pass that region of both `x` and `y` to the consensus function.

Comment: How do we decide which way to line up the strings? (Are you using Biopython? This kind of job sounds like something you should be relying on a bioinformatics library for.)

Comment: Yes I'm using biopython. The resulting string should always start with the beginning of `x` and end with the end of `y`.

Comment: Can you guarantee against input like `OVOVERLAPO`?

Comment: Also I presume you don't know what the `OVERLAP` part is ahead of time?

Comment: The overlap region is totally determined by the input, you don't have to search for it. If `len(x) = 25`, `len(y) = 25`, and `size=20`, you know that the xoverlap region is `x[:20]` and yoverlap is `y[5:]`.

Comment: @elsherbini Great thanks, I'll see what I can do

Comment: @elsherbini: How do you know it's not `y[:20]` and `x[5:]`?

Comment: Because the result always starts with the beginning of x and ends with the end of y.

Comment: You might want to consider looking at the `difflib` library and `SequenceMatcher`...

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a generator that yields each character:

```
def merge_gen(x, y, overhang):
    buffer = ' ' * overhang
    for s in map(set, zip(buffer + x, y + buffer)):
        yield max(s)
```

Where `overhang` is `len(x) - size` (see below)

That works as follows:

```
>>> list(merge_gen('OVERLAPXXX', 'YYYOVERLAP', 3))
['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'L', 'A', 'P', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

You can then implement a `merge` function including the `consensus` function as follows:

```
def merge(x, y, size):
    length = len(x)
    overhang = size - length
    overlap = length - overhang
    gen = merge_gen(x, y, overhang)

    result = ''
    result += ''.join(next(gen) for _ in range(overhang))
    result += consensus(''.join(next(gen) for _ in range(overlap)))
    result += ''.join(next(gen) for _ in range(overhang))
    return result
```

I would *hope* that this is reasonably efficient in Python3; lots of generators, few wasted strings to be discarded, etc.

(*) [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619514/how-to-extract-the-member-from-single-member-set-in-python) this is a fast way of getting a single item from a set. In this case we know the set only has one element, and we just want to extract.

Comment: This seems cool, but at the moment: `x= "OVERLAPxxx", y=yyyOVERLAP; merge(x,y,7) => 'yyyOVEROAPRLA'`

Comment: @elsherbini Fixed, I had a typo :)

Comment: Hmm, expected output would just be `"OVERLAP"` for that input, but instead you get `"yyyOVERLAPxxx"`

Comment: @elsherbini I was basing this on your first example but I'd not realised you've specified `size` as 11 in that rather than 7. I thought `size` was supposed to be the length of the overlapping section - what is it?

Comment: size is the length of the merged string.

Comment: @elsherbini So how is that 11 in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the functionality you were looking for?

```
def consensus(left, right, ignore_blank_padding=True):
    if ignore_blank_padding:
        left = left.strip()
        right = right.strip()

    slide = len(left) + len(right) - 1

    #slides the strings over each other one spot at a time
    solutions = []
    for i in range(slide):
        lft_test = left[-(i+1):]
        rgt_test = right[:min(len(right), i+1)]
        #print(lft_test, rgt_test)
        if lft_test == rgt_test:
            lft_garbage = left[:-(i+1)]
            rgt_garbage = right[min(len(right), (i+1)):]
            solutions.append((lft_garbage, lft_test, rgt_garbage))

    #if more than one overlap combo is found, keeps only the longest
    if len(solutions) > 1:
        sol_lenghts = [len(i[1]) for i in solutions]                
        longest_index = sol_lenghts.index(max(an_lens))
        solutions = solutions[longest_index]
        return solutions
    elif len(solutions) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return solutions[0]

left = 'xxxxHEY'
right = 'HEYxx'
consensus(left, right)
> ('xxxx', 'HEY', 'xx')

left = 'xxHEYHEY'
right = 'HEYHEYxxx'
consensus(left, right)
> ('xx', 'HEYHEY', 'xxx')

left = 'xxHEY '
right = '  HEYHEYxxxx'
consensus(left, right)
> ('xx', 'HEY', 'HEYxxxx')

left = 'HEY'
right = '  HEYHEYxxxx'
consensus(left, right)
> ('', 'HEY', 'HEYxxxx')
```

Left the old answer with the sliding window, but here it is with a specified overlap:

```
def consensus(left, right, size, ignore_blank_padding=True):
    if ignore_blank_padding:
        left = left.strip()
        right = right.strip()

    solutions = None
    lft_test = left[-(size):]
    rgt_test = right[:size]
    if lft_test == rgt_test:
        lft_garbage = left[:-(size)]
        rgt_garbage = right[min(len(right), (size)):]
        solutions = (lft_garbage, lft_test, rgt_garbage)

    return solutions

left = 'xxxxHEY'
right = 'HEYxx'
consensus(left, right, 3)
> ('xxxx', 'HEY', 'xx')

left = 'xxHEYHEY'
right = 'HEYHEYxxx'
consensus(left, right, 6)
> ('xx', 'HEYHEY', 'xxx')

left = 'xxHEY '
right = '  HEYHEYxxxx'
consensus(left, right, 3)
> ('xx', 'HEY', 'HEYxxxx')

left = 'HEY'
right = '  HEYHEYxxxx'
consensus(left, right, 3)
> ('', 'HEY', 'HEYxxxx')
```

Comment: This looks good if you don't know where the strings overlap. In my case I know that the string starts at the beginning of x, ends at the end of y, and has a certain size, so I know which parts are `lft_test`, `lft_garbage` and so on.

Comment: Hmm, I see that.  Definitely shouldn't discard information in the process - I think we could just pass a `size` argument into this and modify where the slicing starts.

Comment: There, added a version for a specified window. They could easily be combined into one function with an optional `size` argument that defaults to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, but uses the "way too many if statements" approach which is hard to read, hard to reason about, and extremely inelegant:

```
def extra_left(x, y, size):
    if size - len(y) > 0:
        return x[:size - len(y)]
    else:
        return ""


def extra_right(x, y, size):
    if size - len(x) > 0:
        return y[len(x) - size:]
    else:
        return ""

def overlap(x, y, size):

    if len(x) < size and len(y) < size:
        x_overlap = x[size - len(y):]
        y_overlap = y[:len(x) - size]
    if len(x) < size and len(y) == size:
        x_overlap = x
        y_overlap = y[:len(x) - size]
    if len(x) < size and len(y) > size:
        x_overlap = x
        y_overlap = y[len(y)-size:size]

    if len(x) == size and len(y) < size:
        x_overlap = x[size - len(y):]
        y_overlap = y
    if len(x) == size and len(y) == size:
        x_overlap = x
        y_overlap = y
    if len(x) == size and len(y) > size:
        x_overlap = x
        y_overlap = y[len(y) - size:]

    if len(x) > size and len(y) < size:
        x_overlap = x[size - len(y):size]
        y_overlap = y
    if len(x) > size and len(y) == size:
        x_overlap = x[:size]
        y_overlap = y
    if len(x) > size and len(y) > size:
        x_overlap = x[:size]
        y_overlap = y[-size:]

    if len(x) + len(y) < size:
        raise RuntimeError("x and y do not overlap with this size")

    return consensus(x_overlap, y_overlap)

def consensus(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    return x


def merge(x, y, size):
    return extra_left(x, y, size) + overlap(x, y, size) + extra_right(x, y, size)
```

Here are some unit tests (using [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/))

```
class Tests:

    def test1(self):
        """
        len(x) < size and len(y) < size:
        xxxOVERLAP---
        ---OVERLAPyyy
        # expected output: xxx + consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP) + yyy
        """
        x = "AAAATTTTTTT"
        y = "TTTTTTTCCC"
        size = 14
        assert merge(x, y, size) == "AAAA" + consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT") + "CCC"

    def test2(self):
        """
        if len(x) < size and len(y) == size:
        # size=10
        OVERLAP---
        OVERLAPyyy
        # expected output: consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP) + yyy
        """
        x = "TTTTTTT"
        y = "TTTTTTTCCC"
        size = 10
        assert merge(x, y, size) == consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT") + "CCC"

    def test3(self):
        """
        if len(x) < size and len(y) > size:
        ---OVERLAP---
        yyyOVERLAPyyy
        """
        x = "TTTTTTT"
        y = "CCCTTTTTTTCCC"
        size = 10
        assert merge(x, y, size) == consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT") + "CCC"

    def test4(self):
        """
        if len(x) == size and len(y) < size:
        # size=10 
        xxxOVERLAP
        ---OVERLAP
        # expected output: xxx + consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP)
        """
        x = "AAATTTTTTT"
        y = "TTTTTTT"
        size = 10
        assert merge(x, y, size) == "AAA" + consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT")

    def test5(self):
        """
        if len(x) == size and len(y) == size:
        # size=7
        OVERLAP
        OVERLAP
        # expected output: consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP)
        """
        x = "TTTTTTT"
        y = "TTTTTTT"
        size = 7
        assert merge(x, y, size) == consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT")

    def test6(self):
        """
        if len(x) == size and len(y) > size:
        # size=10
        --xxxOVERLAP
        yyyyyOVERLAP
        # expected output: consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP)
        """
        x = "AAATTTTTTT"
        y = "CCCCCTTTTTTT"
        size = 10
        assert merge(x, y, size) == "AAA" + consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT")

    def test7(self):
        """
        if len(x) > size and len(y) < size:
        xxxOVERLAPxxx
        ---OVERLAP---
        """
        x = "AAATTTTTTTAAA"
        y = "TTTTTTT"
        size = 10
        assert merge(x, y, size) == "AAA" + consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT")

    def test8(self):
        """
        if len(x) > size and len(y) == size:
        ---OVERLAPxxx
        ---OVERLAP---
        """
        x = "TTTTTTTAAA"
        y = "TTTTTTT"
        size = 7
        assert merge(x, y, size) == consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT")

    def test9(self):
        """
        if len(x) > size and len(y) > size:
        ---OVERLAPxxx
        yyyOVERLAP---
        # expected output: consensus(xOVERLAP, yOVERLAP)
        """
        x = "TTTTTTTAAA"
        y = "CCCTTTTTTT"
        size = 7
        assert merge(x, y, size) == consensus("TTTTTTT", "TTTTTTT")


    def test_error(self):
        """
        # no overlap, produce error:
        xxx---
        ---yyy
        # expected output: error
        """
        x = "AAA"
        y = "TTT"
        size = 7
        with pytest.raises(RuntimeError):
            merge(x, y, size)
```

And they all pass:

```
test_merge.py::Tests::test1 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test2 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test3 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test4 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test5 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test6 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test7 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test8 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test9 PASSED
test_merge.py::Tests::test_error PASSED

====================================================================== 10 passed in 0.02 seconds =======================================================================
```