# How do I change the entries in a set to integers

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the entry of the set to an integer

I've tried isolating the entry and using the "int" function on it

```
contestant = input("Choose a door from the three doors:")
doors = {1,2,3}
prize = random.randint(1,3)
revealable_doors = doors - {int(contestant), int(prize)}
host = int(revealable_doors)
```

I expect that host will be an integer but I keep getting this error

```
host = int(revealable_doors)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

Comment: a set with only one element is still a set...

Comment: Do `host = revealable_doors.pop()` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract the member from single-member set in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619514/how-to-extract-the-member-from-single-member-set-in-python) Use one of the methods indicated and then convert to `int`.

Comment: note also that `revealable_doors` will sometimes be a set with only one element, and will sometimes be a set with two elements

Answer (score 0):

`revealable_doors = doors - {int(contestant), int(prize)}` will return set of one or two elements.

So you cannot just convert set to int as you did in this : `host = int(revealable_doors)`

You can try following code:

```
import random
contestant = input("Choose a door from the three doors:")
doors = {1,2,3}
prize = random.randint(1,3)
revealable_doors = doors - {contestant, prize}
host = revealable_doors.pop()
print(host)
```