# Is there a way to use the enumerate and join functions at the same time?

Tags: python

I am trying to `enumerate` a list of of dictionary definitions which are strings and remove the curly braces. The definitions in the list are taken from a json (dictionary api) which is why i am using join to remove the curly brackets.

When I try doing them at the same time it gives a `"type error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found".` I have tried joining first and then enumerating but that comes with an error too.

I don't believe I can use a for loop because I am assigning all 3 definitions to a single variable (to use in tkinter) and using a for loop would only show definition 3, also because I am not printing the results.

```
Example:
definitions = [{definition1},{definition2},{definition3}]
```

I want to make it so that it shows:

```
result =  1. definition1
          2. definition2
          3. definition3

I have achieved the same result by doing:

result = "1. " + definitions[0] + "\n" + "2. " + definitions[1] + "\n" + "3. " + definitions[2]

but would rather be able to do it in a way that doesn't require me to type out everything manually
```

Comment: _"When I try doing them at the same time it..."_ why not show us the code that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `[{'definition1'}, {'definition2'}, {'definition3'}]` is not a list of dictionaries, it is a list of sets.

So first you need to review [How to extract the member from single-member set in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1619514/1630971) to understand how to get the members out of each set object.

Then you can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) built-in function to get an iterable matching up objects in the list with their position in the list, an f-string to form each line of the output, a list comprehension to collect the lines into a list, and then `string.join()` to combine the lines into a single output string:

```
definitions = [{'definition1'},{'definition2'},{'definition3'}]
out = '\n'.join([f'{n}. {list(d)[0]}' for n, d in enumerate(definitions, start=1)]))
print(out)
```

Result:

```
1. definition1
2. definition2
3. definition3
```

Comment: You can give `enumerate` a second argument to make it start counting at that number (still starts at the 0th index though)

Answer (score 0):

use enumerate + join can do the trick

```py
result = ""
for idx, definition in enumerate(defintions):
    result += f"{idx + 1}: {' '.join(definition.values())} \n"
```

if the definition is a set use

```py
result += f"{idx + 1}: {' '.join(definition)} \n"
```

Comment: Which version of Python did you test this on? I get "AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'values'" in 3.9.

Comment: I have edited, if definition is a set, there is no need to use .values()